# How to test if a ATMega16u2 is working

Tags: atmega, atmega32u4

I have designed a custom ATmega16u2 board, however, I cannot connect to it using USB.

All connections seem to be correct, and I have checked that the voltage regulator is working, regulating it to 3.3V. Also no obvious short circuiting occurs when I connect a battery or USB.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any program loaded on the ATMega? And I don't think the regulator is working or there is some other problem. A 3.3V regulator should not output 3.6V.

Comment: I mistyped as 3.6 not 3.3. I cannot load any program on to it as the USB was the intended method to load programs onto it

Comment: IIRC Arduinos are pre-programmed with a bootloader program that allows other programs to be loaded by USB. I'm not sure that USB can be used to load the original program. Usually you have to use ICSP (in-circuit serial programming)

Answer (score 2):

Your MCU has USB interface but it does not do anything without a program to use the USB interface.

If the MCU has no program loaded to use the USB interface, it will not do anything if connected to a PC.

At bare minimum you need to use other means to flash a bootloader that can use the USB interface to download other programs.

Answer (score -2):

You should to remove your IC from the board, and check continuity between VCC and GND pins. If you have continuity then that IC is dead. Also, a short current can appear between any other pin, GPIO, interrupt pins, ADC pin etc respect to GND.

Comment: Of course there will be continuity between pins and GND if you simply test with a multimeter. The protection diodes will be there to conduct. The hardware is likely fine, there is just no software to run the USB.